# pre-post comparison based on baseline scores

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have pre- and post-intervention data for 50 participants. I expect participants who scored lower at baseline to improve their score more after the intervention, and who scored higher at baseline to improve their score less than those who scored low at baseline. I would like to examine this by creating 4 groups based on the baseline scores (high, mid-high, mid-low, low), and by evaluating if there are differences among these 4 groups in gain scores (post-pre). I would like to know what the best way would be to do it. Would analyzing the gain scores in an ANOVA with the grouping variable as the between-subject factor be okay? Since the grouping variable is created based on the baseline scores, I'm not 100% sure if it is an appropriate way to do it.

Comment: This will almost certainly  occur because of regression toward the mean artifact which means you shouldn't draw any substantive conclusions.

Comment: Thanks David for your response. Could you elaborate on what you meant by saying "This" at the beginning? What will almost certainly occur?